# Using latest Docker image in BitBucket pipe command

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a Bitbucket pipeline that runs a pipe using a version number tag as follows:

```
script:
        - mkdir meta
        - pipe: myteam/bladepackager-pipeline:1.0.8
          variables: ...
```

I would prefer to have it automatically resolve the latest tagged version of the Docker image, so I tried:

```
script:
        - mkdir meta
        - pipe: myteam/bladepackager-pipeline:latest
          variables: ...
```

But I get an error message from my BitBucket pipeline run that says

> Your pipe name is in an invalid format. Check the name of the pipe and try again.

Is there a way to specify `latest` rather than a specific tag?

Comment: Do you have an image with the latest tag? I have my custom pipe be ran with the tag and it works perfectly fine. You might wanna add `docker://` prefix  to the image name tho

Answer (score 0):

The tag latest, itself is a tag, it does not mean the latest tag. so if you want to use images with this tag, you have to make docker with that tag.

Comment: yes, the Repo does contain a `latest` tag

Answer (score 0):

The

```
- pipe: aaa/bbbb:1.2.3
```

syntax refers to a git repository hosted in the bitbucket, e.g. bitbucket.org/aaa/bbbb, whereas the

```
- pipe: docker://registry.example.com/aaa/bbbb:tag
```

refers to a docker image in any registry.

The `:latest` tag can only be used with the docker syntax. For the bare pipe syntax I guess you can only try git refs? Maybe `:main` or `:master` would be valid? Never managed it to work, please reach back if you succeed.